# SQL query that returns specific string if column is null?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, null

When an SQL query returns null, I'm wondering if it's possible to have it return a specific string like "Unknown" instead of null.

I'm currently doing this on the JavaScript side and was wondering if there's a faster way to do this on the server.

Example (I realize the following syntax doesn't exist):

```
SELECT Customers.Email (RETURN "Unknown" IF NULL)
```

I imagine it's possible with a CASE? But filling up my query with CASE statements will slow this whole action down rather than speed it up.

Comment: Isnull will do the job

Comment: Coalesce is the standard function

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`coalesce`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT COALESCE(email, 'Unknown')
FROM   customers
```

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL you can use [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

```
SELECT IFNULL(Customers.Email, 'Unknown') AS Email
```

Answer (score 3):

While `COALESCE` is the best solution, there is also `CASE`
This can be handy if you have to deal with either nulls or empty strings.

```
SELECT CASE Customers.Email
    WHEN NULL THEN 'Unknown'
    WHEN '' THEN 'Unknown'
    ELSE Customers.Email
    END AS Email
FROM Customers;

SELECT CASE
    WHEN Customers.Email IS NULL THEN 'Unknown'
    WHEN TRIM(Customers.Email) = '' THEN 'Unknown'
    ELSE Customers.Email
    END AS Email
FROM Customers;
```

Comment: Why is `COALESCE` the best solution? IFNULL seems so much simpler and easier to read.

Comment: `COALESCE: Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.` You can use `IFNULL` to substitue a single value, while `COALESCE` takes a list, `IFNULL(IFNULL(customer.email, customer.altemail),'unknown')` becomes this `COALESCE(customer.email, customer.altemail, 'unknown')` Since COALESCE is more powerfull I always use this. Didn't experience any performace impacts so far.